# Recurrence table doesn't like non-linearity?

Tags: difference-equations

When I evaluate the following `RecurrenceTable` expression

```
RecurrenceTable[
  {x[n + 1] == x[n] + 0.1 y[n], 
   y[n + 1] == y[n] + 0.1 z[n],
   z[n] == x[n] + 1,
   x[1] == 2., y[1] == 3.}, 
  {x, y, z}, {n, 1, 10}]
```

it does what I expect. However, if I change the `x[n] + 1` into `x[n]^2`, it no longer works, despite the fact that there is no circularity in the table. I don't see why it would make a difference what `z` is as a function of `x`.

What's the reason for this behavior? Is it documented?

Comment: The Scope - Difference-Algebraic Equations section of the [reference page for RecurrenceTable](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) gives an example of "a linear difference-algebraic equation with constant coefficients".  Maybe a nonlinear one is outside the scope?  In your example, you could define `z[n_] := x[n]^2` outside the `RecurrenceTable` I think.

Answer (score 6):

Eliminating the decimal points fixes the problem

```
N[RecurrenceTable[
{x[n + 1] == x[n] + 1/10 y[n], 
y[n + 1] == y[n] + 1/10z[n],
z[n] == x[n]^2,
x[1] == 2, y[1] == 3}, {x, y, z}, {n, 1, 10}]]
```

gives

```
{{2.,3.,4.},{2.3,3.4,5.29},{2.64,3.929,6.9696},{3.0329,4.62596,9.19848}, 
{3.4955,5.54581,12.2185},{4.05008,6.76766,16.4031},{4.72684,8.40797,22.343}, 
{5.56764,10.6423,30.9986},{6.63187,13.7421,43.9817}, 
{8.00608,18.1403,64.0973}}
```

Perhaps it is a pattern matching problem fighting inexact decimals